# Get Last Value Based on Timestamp and Value Group in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the last value of a group based on a timestamp using Snowflake.

I have the following table,

```
| ISSUE_ID | ISSUE_ID | FIELD_TIME | FIELD_NAME | FIELD_VALUE| STATUS
| -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------| ----------| ----------
|19229| X1|2021-08-01 09:04:35.234000000 +00:00|Status|10010|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-01 09:04:35.234000000 +00:00|Number of Products|55|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-01 09:04:35.234000000 +00:00|Number of SKU not created|34|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-01 09:04:35.234000000 +00:00|Number of SKU live|21|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-01 09:04:35.234000000 +00:00|Date of SKU live|2021-08-12|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-08 06:19:05.209000000 +00:00|Status|10010|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-08 11:43:51.953000000 +00:00|Status|10010|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-12 06:12:15.185000000 +00:00|Number of Products|55|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-12 06:27:32.199000000 +00:00|Number of SKU not created|31|PENDING
|19229| X1|2021-08-12 09:14:16.178000000 +00:00|Number of SKU live|24|PENDING
```

I would like the table to have one column to each value (e.g., Number of Products, Date of SKU Live..etc) and that column only has the last value of that day. Like the following table,

```
| ISSUE_ID | ISSUE_ID | FIELD_TIME | Number of Products | Number of SKU live| Date of SKU live|Number of SKU not created|Work_In_Progress_Date|Pending_Date|Status|Resolution|
|--------|----------|---------- |----------|----------|----------|----------|----------
|19229   | X1       |2021-08-01 |55        |21        |2021-08-01|34        |          |             |PENDING              | null
|19229   | X1       |2021-08-08 |          |          |          |          |          |             |PENDING              | null
|19229   | X1       |2021-08-12 |55        |24        |2021-08-01|31        |2021-08-12|   2021-08-12|PENDING              | null
```

I have tried `last_value(FIELD_VALUE) over (partition by FIELD_NAME, ISSUE_ID order by field_time)` but it gives me duplicated values with 23 rows and not 3 rows.
I have tried `lag()` as well with no luck.
Please if someone has an idea on how to do this conversion help me out.

Here is my SQL code,

```
select
       t.ISSUE_ID, t.issue_name,
--        t.created_date,
       t.field_time::date as field_time,
       max(case when field_name = 'Number of Products' then field_value end) as Number_of_Products,
       max(case when field_name = 'Number of SKU live' then field_value end) as Number_of_SKU_Live,
       max(case when field_name = 'Number of SKU not created' then field_value end) as Number_of_SKU_Not_Created,
       max(case when field_name = 'Date of SKU live' then field_value end) as Date_of_SKU_Live,
       max(case when field_value = '10020' then date(t.field_time) end) as Work_In_Progress_Date,
       max(case when field_value = '10010' then date(t.field_time) end) as Pending_Date,
       t.status, t.resolution
       from
(select fh.ISSUE_ID,
       i.issue_name,
       date(i.created_date) as created_date,
       fh.TIME as field_time,
       f.name as field_name,
       fh.value as field_value,
       i.status,
       i.resolution
from JIRA.ISSUE_FIELD_HISTORY fh
         left join JIRA.FIELD f on fh.FIELD_ID = f.ID and f._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
         left join (select i0.created as created_date,r.name as resolution, i0.id, i0.key as issue_name, i0.status as status_id, s.name as status
                    from JIRA.issue i0
                             left join JIRA.status s on i0.status = s.ID
                             left join JIRA.RESOLUTION r on i0.RESOLUTION = r.ID
             where i0._FIVETRAN_DELETED = 0
             and i0.key like 'PIM%')
             i on i.id = fh.ISSUE_ID
where fh.ISSUE_ID in (select ID from ISSUE where PROJECT = 10041)
and fh.FIELD_ID in ('customfield_10067', 'customfield_10063', 'customfield_10066', 'customfield_10068', 'status', 'resolution')
-- and issue_name = 'PIM-11'
qualify row_number() over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date, field_name order by field_time desc) = 1
order by field_time) t
group by issue_id, issue_name,created_date, field_time::date, status, resolution
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qualify` to get the most recent value:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date, field_name order by field_time desc) = 0;
```

Then aggregate:

```
select issue_id, field_time::date,
       max(case when field_name = 'Number of Products' then field_value end) as number_of_products,
       max(case when field_name = 'Number of SKU live' then field_value end) as number_of_sku_live,
       . . . 
from (select t.*
      from t
      qualify row_number() over (partition by issue_id, field_time::date, field_name order by field_time desc) = 0
     ) t
group by issue_id, field_time::date
```

Comment: The max(case when..) solved the issue without qualify. This saved me big time. Thank you.

Comment: In some cases it's returning zero rows from some 'issue_id', how can I overcome this? @Gordon

Comment: @Nabaa . . . This query would return all issues that are in your table, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: it would duplicate the values for some issues - and some uses zero. I am not sure how this result is happening - I edited the actual question to paste my code if you would like to check it. Thank you